# SVN revision in a JMX bean

Tags: svn, jmx

I am creating Java components through a maven build. I would like to have JMX bean for them to output the svn revision and the branch and perhaps the checkout and build date (so monitoring tool can keep a look at it)

Any suggestions how to do this. I guess I would need some sort of SVN hooks for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the [`svn:keywords`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html) Property to your source file.
Example:

```
$> svn propset svn:keywords "Id Revision" MyClass.java
```

Inside your MyClass.java:

```
private static final string svn_id = "$Id$";
private static final string svn_rev = "$Revision$";
```

The result will look like this on each commit:

```
private static final string svn_id = "$Id: MyClass.java 123 2012-01-04 13:36:23Z bk $";
private static final string svn_rev = "$Revision: 123 $";
```